How to calculate the Params and MACs of Kolmogorov-Arnold Networks(KAN)?
I used efficient_kan(https://github.com/Blealtan/efficient-kan) to build my KAN layer. And I noticed that get_model_complexity_info from ptflops can not calculate the Params and MACs of KAN_Linear.0 Param and MAC
I tried some other methods but they didn't work, such as profile from thop.What should i do?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I tried to use efficient-kan and it did not work either. You can try other libraries:

C# implementation:  http://openkan.org/DLpiecewise.html
C++ implementation: http://openkan.org/DLpiecewiseCPP.html
C# spline http://openkan.org/DLsplines.html

The training is done by the different method, not Broyden, details are here:
http://openkan.org/KANscore.html

Or use original MIT code, which can be found by keyword pykan   It is about 100 slower than MLP, but it works and it is Python.
